# Delphi xe2 Enabled TLS 1.2 in Indy 10.5.8.0

Tags: delphi, indy, tls1.2

I using Delphi xe2, but In Win32 application I cannot see TLS 1.2 in IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL .
I need recompile Indy or I need enabled something to show this TLS version??

[image]

Comment: It's been added when v10.5.8 has been developed ([precisely here](https://github.com/graemeg/indy/commit/c7d112a19bb705e2c322642bcd67d0d14fe9badc#diff-fc3d70c144188de48f2cfea5ffa8c5db)). Don't you want to install the latest version?

Comment: 10.5.8 is very old. The current version is 10.6.2, and there are a lot of differences, fixes, and features added after 10.5.8. Please upgrade.

Comment: Are need recompile and reinstall Indy in Delphi, I do It and the problem was Solved, and Now god Help with other bugs